# MySQL: How can I optimize delete operation based on time?

Tags: mysql

So my colleague created this query which will run every hour on a table with 500K+ records.

```
Delete from table where timestamp> now() - interval 24 hour
```

I am having a feeling that this would be slower as it is computing time at each row, am I right? How can I optimize it?

**Update**

With 2.8 Million records it took around 12 seconds to delete the matched rows.

Comment: "Am I right?".  Don't rely on your feelings as a way top spot performance bottlenecks.  Start by running `explain` on the delete statement to see what it says: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html.

Comment: Another way to test if your theory is correct would be to run the query with a fixed timestamp instead of `now() - interval 24 hour`.  Is it significantly faster?  If not, you are barking up the wrong tree ...

Comment: My guess is that the way to make this significantly faster would be to create an index on the `timestamp` column ... so that that delete statement doesn't have to test all rows in the table.  But adding an extra index may have performance impacts in other areas.

Comment: @StephenC The question was updated with metrics now

Comment: And ... what about if you try the alternatives that I suggested?

Comment: My point is that the measurement that you added are is a single data point.  It doesn't in any way help us to find an answer to your question.

Comment: Simple answer - yes, pre-calculate it to be sure.  Otherwise, you are relying on the optimisation that may or may not be present in the engine.

Answer (score 0):

> I am having a feeling that this would be slower as it is computing time at each row, am I right?

No, the time calculation is done once at the start of the query. It is a constant value for the duration of the query.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now says:

> `NOW()` returns a constant time that indicates the time at which the statement began to execute.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/where-optimization.html says:

> Constant expressions used by indexes are evaluated only once.

You also asked:

> How can I optimize it?

The easiest thing to do is make sure there is an index on the `timestamp` column.

A different solution is to use partitioning by the `timestamp` column, and drop 1 partition per day. This blog has a description of this solution: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint

Answer (score 0):

- run the query more frequently (say, hourly)
- have an index on that column
- `PARTITION BY RANGE` and use `DROP PARTITION`; suggest by hour; see [*Partition*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint)
- More tips:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig